# Multiple Y-Axis with JSON data in C3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, c3.js

When trying to map json data to mutiple y axis in c3 js, second axis does not scale to the data, instead shows 0-1. Any ideas to correct it ?

Comment: Hi, can you create a jsfiddle or something to look at? it will be easier to answer this way

Comment: Hi, Thanks ! but i fixed it, there was a key mismatch ! that is why it didn't scale properly ! thanks again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#chart',
  data: {
    json: [{
        "name": "google search",
        "Lead": 250,
        "Conversion": 59,
        "Rate": 50
      },
      {
        "name": "facebook advertisement",
        "Lead": 104,
        "Conversion": 20,
        "Rate": 60
      },
      {
        "name": "ST Ads",
        "Lead": 200,
        "Conversion": 123,
        "Rate": 70
      }
    ],
    keys: {
      x: 'name',
      value: ['Lead', 'Conversion', 'Rate'],
    },
    axes: {
      'Rate': 'y2'
    },
    type: 'bar',
    types: {
      'Rate': 'line'
    }
  },
  axis: {
    x: {
      type: 'category'
    },
    y2: {
      show: true
    }
  }
});
```